# HeidiSQL- Importing csv; Incorrect string value

Tags: sql, ms-access, heidisql

I am a beginner to database management. Currently,I am trying to import a csv file using HeidiSQL from MS Access. I was able to import 5 of 6 tables properly. On the last one, I am constantly getting

```
Incorrect string value: '\xE1' to ...' for column 'Desc' at row 1248856 *
```

For numerous rows.  From my research, I've tried numerous permutations of chinging the data type of "desc" to text, longblob,
changing the "default collation" to: utf8mb4-unicode_ci, changing "encoding" to UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4).

But nothing has worked thus far. Can someone tell me how to correct this?

Comment: DESC is a reserved word in Access. Should not use reserved words as names. However, that might not be the issue here. The error only occurs when the data begins with \ character?

Comment: desc is the name of the field in the Heidisql table. None of the data in desc begins with a '\'

Comment: Could you post sample data from that CSV file?

Comment: I can't post the actual data, but here is a subset of the strings inside the 'desc' field. Basically it can contain a whole slew of characters:

    `Comm Type changed from 'X' to 'Z'`
    `new account 492-A94MF added.`
    `sex changed from '' to 'FEMALE'`

Comment: so this character appears in desc: á. I think it may be causing the issue. Does anyone know how to circumvent this (if this is the cause)? The table omitted records with á and _

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by changing encoding to "Western European" and removing backslashes that were escaping " characters that surrounded my fields.